# iOS 11 UIBarButtonItem ImageView size bug

Tags: ios, image, size, uinavigationbar, ios11

Hello this morning with iOS 11 I discovered lots of bugs that I did not have with iOS 10. I have corrected most bugs except two bugs, the profil image at the top right here

Code button :

```
UIImageView* v = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 35, 35)];
    v.image = img;
    v.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    v.layer.cornerRadius = 17.5;

    UIBarButtonItem* rightBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:v];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBtn;
```

///// iOS 10 /////

[image]

///// iOS 11 /////

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In iOS 11 you must need us auto-layout instead of frames

Like below

```
    myButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: customViewButton.width).isActive = true
    myButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: customViewButton.height).isActive = true
```

Comment: Thank you very much and how to solve the padding problem of the first uitableviewcell? I use this library for header scroll GSKStretchyHeaderView

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this
with the following code :

```
[v.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:35].active = YES;

[v.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:35].active = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem with use UIbutton.

Answer (score 0):

@victor bill's answer works like a charm, but I would like to mention that this doesn't work if you don't set the frame for the button first. *Only* setting the width and height anchor makes the button disappear altogether in my app.

```
v =  [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 35, 35)];
[v.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:35].active = YES;
[v.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:35].active = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set a fixed size to your image/button/UIView in general, this is the Swift 4 code:

```
    yourButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100.0).isActive = true
    yourButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30.0).isActive = true
```

You have to set width and height manually using two constraints and set them to active.